# Optimizing a Unity CharacterSelection

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

in my game, I got some teachers to make the player increase his skills. At the moment, there are 12 guys, so I wrote a base class for them.

This class selects the correct data from its own "teacherDataClass". The data is set by an index from the Editor.

My code:

```
 [SerializeField]
 int teacherIndex; // set an index in the editor -> selection of teacher

    NpcTeacherData teacherData; // the data class

    private void Start()
    {
        NpcTeacherData[] teachers = // Collection of all teachers
        {
            new TeacherAlchemist(),
            new TeacherBlacksmith(),
            new TeacherBowyer(),
            new TeacherButcher(),
            new TeacherHunter(),
            new TeacherInnkeeper(),
            new TeacherJuggler(),
            new TeacherMessenger(),
            new TeacherPriest(),
            new TeacherTamer(),
            new TeacherThief(),
            new TeacherTownGuard()
        };

        teacherData = teachers[teacherIndex]; // Get the right teacher by the index
    }
```

So this looks fine and this works fine. If you do not want to use the Editor, you could compare the tag of the teacherObject like this way

```
NpcTeacherData teacherData; // the data class

private void Start()
{
    switch (gameObject.tag) // compare the tag of the teacher and set its class
        {
            case "TeacherAlchemist":
                teacherData = new TeacherAlchemist();
                break;
            case "TeacherBlacksmith":
                teacherData = new TeacherBlacksmith();
                break;

            //...
        }
}
```

But I do not like these ways that much :/ Are there any better possibilities? Like a DropDownSelection in the Editor maybe?

I tried

```
[SerializeField]
object script; // Place the right data class here

[SerializeField]
object script as NpcTeacherData; // Place the right data class here
```

But this did not work.

I just want to optimize it :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use an *enum* to achieve this?

It would be something like this:

```
public enum TeacherType
{
    TeacherAlchemist,
    TeacherBlacksmith,
    TeacherBowyer,
    TeacherButcher,
    TeacherHunter,
    TeacherInnkeeper,
    TeacherJuggler,
    TeacherMessenger,
    TeacherPriest,
    TeacherTamer,
    TeacherThief,
    TeacherTownGuard
}

public TeacherType type;

private NpcTeacherData teacherData;

private void Start()
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case TeacherType.TeacherAlchemist:
            teacherData = new TeacherAlchemist();
            break;

        //...
    }
}
```

However it doesn't differ a lot from your first solution (only choice is a bit easier since the type is shown instead of an index).

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: `gameObject.tag` generates garbage and is slower since it is comparing string. `Enum` should do fine. Even better, use `Enum` + `Dictionary` to map that instead of many if or switch check.

Comment: True that using a dictionary too could be even better. And thanks for the edit (copy/paste errors are the worst)!

Comment: No problem. Just a type. When I said Dictionary I actually meant something lke this: `Dictionary<TeacherType, Action> dic`. Then you add all the Enumes with their actions to the Dictionary like this `dic.Add(TeacherType.TeacherAlchemist, ()=>{teacherData = new TeacherAlchemist();})`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Editor GUI Popup. Here is how you can make a dropdown/popup -

```
public string[] options = new string[] {"TeacherAlchemist","TeacherBlacksmith","TeacherBowyer","TeacherButcher","TeacherHunter","TeacherInnkeeper","TeacherJuggler","TeacherMessenger","TeacherPriest","TeacherTamer","TeacherThief","TeacherTownGuar"};
public int selectedIndex = 0;
```

Then Use OnGUI function to store selected value

```
void OnGUI()
{
    selectedIndex = EditorGUILayout.Popup("TeacherDataClass", selectedIndex, options);
}
```

You can find [reference here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Popup.html).

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to use OnGUI :) I want to select the dataClass 1 time. The OnGUI method would be called all the game long.